# Developing a Chrome Kiosk App on a non-managed Chromebox

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chromium, google-chrome-os

tl;dr I want to use an API that only works for Chrome Kiosk Apps. How can I run my app locally as a kiosk app such that I can access these APIs?

Hey All,

I am trying to develop an application that uses the [chrome.audio API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/audio). Though the docs do not say so, upon loading an unpacked app on my Chromebox I get a warning saying "'audio' is only allowed to run in kiosk apps sessions, but this is a regular user session."

So I began trying to get the app launched in kiosk mode. I have modified the manifest.json file to claim kiosk mode: "kiosk_enabled":true. I navigate to chrome://extensions and click "Manage Kiosk Applications" but when I put in the app ID provided when loading my unpacked extension, I always get a message saying "Invalid App ID".

It has been suggested to me that the only way to load a kiosk app is either through the admin console (not applicable to me since my device is unmanaged) or by publishing the app to the Chrome Web Store, which is crazy overkill since I have not even developed my app yet, I just want to see if this API can provide functionality I need.

In summary, my question is this:

**How can I run my app locally as a kiosk app such that I can access these APIs?**

Comment: It says in [How to developer a Kiosk App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled#Develop) that kiosks apps are almost the same as chrome apps, so try testing them like you would a chrome app. You can also give the [Create a kiosk app with Chrome App Builder](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6137027?hl=en) a try.

Comment: @noogui thank you for your comment. I am unable to launch an app in kiosk mode which is the only way to get access to these API's that are only available in kiosk mode. The apps launch fine in user mode but are still denied access to the relevant API's. The Chrome App Builder has the same problem: I cannot run it in kiosk mode locally.