# Chrome audio API is undefined (Chrome OS app)

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

In our Chrome App for Chrome OS (yes, we know that Chrome Apps are being discontinued, but this is a kiosk app and kiosk mode is not yet supported for PWAs), we would like to use the [`chrome.audio` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/audio) to display system audio volume and mute status. We have `audio` added to the permissions in our manifest.json, but `chrome.audio` is returning `undefined`. Is there something else we need to do to enable the `chrome.audio` API?

Comment: Other than a bug in Chrome, without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve)  I can only guess you're not using it in an app script like the background script (e.g. a webview script can't use it) or you didn't reload the app after editing manifest.json and code.

Comment: That was the issue. Moved it to a background script and it works - thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm actually it seems that now it only works in kiosk mode, but when running the app in a user or guest session it still returns chrome.audio as undefined even from the background script. Is this API only supported in kiosk mode?

Comment: I should add that chrome.permissions.getAll also does not return the "audio" permission when not in kiosk mode (it exists in the manifest.json)

Comment: Okay according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884850/developing-a-chrome-kiosk-app-on-a-non-managed-chromebox it only works in kiosk mode (of course Google doesn't bother to say that anywhere...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chrome.audio` API only works in a background script [and only in kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884850/developing-a-chrome-kiosk-app-on-a-non-managed-chromebox), not in a content script or in a user/guest session. Moving the call to the background script and running in kiosk mode fixes the issue. It would be nice if Google would bother to document these things...

H/T [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008592/chrome-audio-api-is-undefined-chrome-os-app#comment107934390_61008592)